# what is located under /var directory?

Tags: macos

Today I was checking running processes and found a process running as root from this location, I am on osx maverics. I wanted to know what kind of process might be that's running from /var folder that too as root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good writeup on linfo.org describing the [/var directory](http://www.linfo.org/var.html). In summary, it is used for **var**iable information, like cache, logs, lock files, spool files, etc. Some executables will reside in this tree, like shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can type "man hier" to get information about the filesystem. From the man page:

```
NAME
     hier -- layout of filesystems

DESCRIPTION
     A historical sketch of the filesystem hierarchy.  The modern OS X
     filesystem is documented in the ``File System Programming Guide'' avail-
     able on Apple Developer.

[omitted]
     /var/         multi-purpose log, temporary, transient, and spool files

               at/        timed command scheduling files; see at(1)
               backups/   misc. backup files
               db/        misc. automatically generated system-specific database files
               log/       misc. system log files

               mail/      user mailbox files
               run/       system information files describing various info about system since it
                          was booted

                          utmpx       database of current users; see utmpx(5)

               rwho/      rwho data files; see rwhod(8), rwho(1), and ruptime(1)
               spool/     misc. printer and mail system spooling directories

                          mqueue/     undelivered mail queue; see sendmail(8)

               tmp/       temporary files that are kept between system reboots
               folders/   per-user temporary files and caches
```

...